# Is there a mock tracer implementation for io.helidon.tracing.Tracer?

Tags: helidon

Currently migrating from Helidon 2.x to 3.x , hence making the tracing related changes.
Previously was using MockTracer to test spans in Unit Tests. Would like to know if there is a similar alternative to io.opentracing.mock.MockTracer in helidon 3.x

Currently could not find any alternative to MockTracer. Previously was using tracer.finishedSpans() method in UTs

Answer (score 1):

You can get a noOp tracer, see https://helidon.io/docs/v3/apidocs/io.helidon.tracing/io/helidon/tracing/Tracer.html

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: I think, we need better bots as above is a javadoc link and not something random :)